# UIScrollView 1D Bouncing but 2D Scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, bounce

The project I'm currently working requires that a `UIScrollView` to scroll vertically and horizontally, however, it must only bounce vertically.  Is this possible? I noticed that there is a `verticalBouncing` and `horizontalBouncing` property in the declaration, could that be the answer?

Comment: Is it really easier to create a SO question instead of just testing it?

Comment: I've tried, but I was unable to access those properties. `valueForKey:` returns a `id` object, but `horizontalBouncing` is an int within a struct.

Comment: can you provide the code what _exactly_ you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access `@package` ivars directly. However, you can register yourself as delegate of `UIScrollView` and implemenet this code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float maxX = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width;

    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    offset.x = MAX(MIN(maxX, offset.x), 0);
    scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about using that delegate method.